# Permission depends on field django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write little project which is using django rest framework and I have the Book model and rest api for that:

```
#models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LANGUAGES)
    publication_date = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Книга'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Книги'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The next serialiser:

```
#serializers.py
class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=120)
    language = serializers.CharField()
    publication_date = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Book.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)

        instance.publication_date = validated_data.get(
            'publication_date',
            instance.publication_date
        )

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

And the next view:

```
#views.py
class BookView(APIView):

    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

    def get(self, request):
        books = Book.objects.all()
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response({"books": serializer.data})

    def post(self, request):

        book = request.data.get('book')
        # Create an article from the above data
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=book)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            book_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({"success": "Book '{}' created successfully".format(book_saved.name)})

    def put(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        saved_book = get_object_or_404(Book.objects.all(), pk=pk)
        data = request.data.get('book')
        serializer = BookSerializer(instance=saved_book, data=data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            book_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "success": "Book '{}' updated successfully".format(book_saved.name)
        })

    def delete(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        book = get_object_or_404(Book.objects.all(), pk=pk)
        book.delete()
        return Response(
            {"message": "Book with id `{}` has been deleted.".format(pk)},
            status=204
        )
```

How I can to implement permission which depends on `publication_date` field, literally if `publication_date` more than current date, then get request is available only for admins.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Book.objects.all()` everywhere, define a function:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return Book.objects.all()
    else:
        return Book.objects.filter(publication_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Then call it like `self.get_queryset(request)`.

This will only make books published earlier than right now to be visible to non-admins.

Also, you have a lot of boilerplate code.  You should probably be using [`ModelViewSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)